# Google Cloud Stackdriver Profiler GKE installation

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a java dropwizard microservice running on Google Kubernetes Engine.
I'm trying to integrate stackdriver profiler to my project.

I added agent as described in offical documentation. When I try to run my docker container, I get following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library /opt/cprof/profiler_java_agent.so in absolute path, with error: Error relocating /opt/cprof/profiler_java_agent.so: __printf_chk: symbol not found
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM java:openjdk-8-jre-alpine

COPY build/libs/com.company.my-api-*.jar /opt/app/com.company.my-api.jar
COPY config.yml /opt/app/config.yml


RUN   apk update \
  &&   apk add ca-certificates wget libc6-compat \
  &&   update-ca-certificates

RUN mkdir -p /opt/cprof && \
    wget -q -O- https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-profiler/java/latest/profiler_java_agent.tar.gz \
    | tar xzv -C /opt/cprof


WORKDIR /opt/app/

EXPOSE 8028

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-agentpath:/opt/cprof/profiler_java_agent.so=-cprof_service=myApi,-logtostderr", "-jar", "com.companyny-api.jar", "server", "config.yml"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend that you report this to our product team to help investigate your Stackdriver Profiler issue further. Please ask your question on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that this is a Beta release of Stackdriver Profiler. This feature is not covered by any SLA or deprecation policy and might be subject to backward-incompatible changes.

The error you are getting seems to be a known issue with Alpine base image and found some other users reported the same. It is the operating system that is incompatible with the Stackdriver Profiler. These documentations ([1](https://ghost.kontena.io/docker-for-mac-glibc-issues/) & [2](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8528))are a good read. I would recommend to try with non-Apline base image and it should work as it worked for others.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes you are right, when I switched to `openjdk:8-jre-slim` docker image, it worked.